# How can I handle pagination with Scrapy and Splash, if the href of the button is javascript:void(0)

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to scrape the names and links of universities from this website: https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/world-university-rankings/2021, and encountered a problem when dealing with pagination, as the href of the button which directs to the next page is javascript:void(0), so I could not reach the next page with scrapy.Request() or response.follow(), is there any way to handle pagination like this?

[screen shot of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxngw.png)

[screen shot of the  tag and href](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25OzT.png)

The URL of this website does not contain params, and if the next page button is clicked, the URL remains unchanged, so I could not handle pagination by altering the URL.

The code snippet below can only fetch the names and links of the universities on the first and second page:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class UniSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'uni'
    allowed_domains = ['www.topuniversities.com']

    script = """
    function main(splash, args)
      splash:set_user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36")
      splash.private_mode_enabled = false
      assert(splash:go(args.url))
      assert(splash:wait(3))

      return {
        html = splash:html()
      }
    end
    """

    next_page = """
    function main(splash, args)
        splash:set_user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36")
        splash.private_mode_enabled = false
        assert(splash:go(args.url))
        assert(splash:wait(3))

        local btn = assert(splash:jsfunc([[
        function(){
        document.querySelector("#alt-style-pagination a.page-link.next").click()
      }
        ]]))
        assert(splash:wait(2))
        btn()

        splash:set_viewport_full()
        assert(splash:wait(3))

        return {
          html = splash:html()
        }
    end
    """

    def start_requests(self):
        yield SplashRequest(
            url="https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/world-university-rankings/2021",
            callback=self.parse, endpoint="execute",
            args={"lua_source": self.script})

    def parse(self, response):
        for uni in response.css("a.uni-link"):
            uni_link = response.urljoin(uni.css("::attr(href)").get())
            yield {
                "name": uni.css("::text").get(),
                "link": uni_link
            }

        yield SplashRequest(
            url=response.url,
            callback=self.parse, endpoint="execute",
            args={"lua_source": self.next_page}
        )
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need splash for this simple website.

Try loading following link instead:

https://www.topuniversities.com/sites/default/files/qs-rankings-data/en/2057712.txt

This has all the universities, the website loads this file/json **only once** and then show information with pagination.

Here is the short code (not using scrapy):

```
from requests import get
from json import loads, dumps
from lxml.html import fromstring

url = "https://www.topuniversities.com/sites/default/files/qs-rankings-data/en/2057712.txt"
html = get(url, stream=True)

## another approach for loading json
# jdata = loads(html.content.decode())

jdata = html.json()
for x in jdata['data']:
    core_id = x['core_id']
    country = x['country']
    city = x['city']
    guide = x['guide']
    nid = x['nid']
    title = x['title']
    logo = x['logo']
    score = x['score']
    rank_display = x['rank_display']
    region = x['region']
    stars = x['stars']
    recm = x['recm']
    dagger = x['dagger']

    ## convert title to text
    soup = fromstring(title)
    title = soup.xpath(".//a/text()")[0]

    print ( title )
```

Above code prints 'title' of individual universities, try saving it in CSV/Excel file along with other available columns. Result looks like:

```
Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT) 
Stanford University
Harvard University
California Institute of Technology (Caltech)
University of Oxford
ETH Zurich - Swiss Federal Institute of Technology
University of Cambridge
Imperial College London
```